# ASP.NET DropDownList AutoPostBack in UpdatePanel using JQuery ComboBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, updatepanel, autopostback

I have an issue where I am using an asp.net dropdownlist inside of an update panel with autopostback set to true. Here is my drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdownFacility" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Facility_SelectionChanged" />
```

In my update panel, the updatemode is set to conditional and I have this for a trigger:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dropdownFacility" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Issue is that when I turn the drop down list into a JQuery [Combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox), then the autopostback functionality doesn't work. I tested it without applying the JQuery combobox functionality and then the autopostback did work. I basically took their script code from the link above and applied it to my drop down:

```
(function ($)
{
    $.widget("custom.combobox", {
        _create: function ()
        {
            this.wrapper = $("<span>")
          .addClass("custom-combobox")
          .insertAfter(this.element);

            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton();
        },

        _createAutocomplete: function ()
        {
            var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

            this.input = $("<input>")
          .appendTo(this.wrapper)
          .val(value)
          .attr("title", "")
          .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
          .autocomplete({
              delay: 0,
              minLength: 0,
              source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
          })
          .tooltip({
              tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });

            this._on(this.input, {
                autocompleteselect: function (event, ui)
                {
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    this._trigger("select", event, {
                        item: ui.item.option
                    });
                },

                autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
            });
        },

        _createShowAllButton: function ()
        {
            var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;

            $("<a>")
          .attr("tabIndex", -1)
          .attr("title", "Show All Items")
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo(this.wrapper)
          .button({
              icons: {
                  primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
              },
              text: false
          })
          .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
          .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
          .mousedown(function ()
          {
              wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
          })
          .click(function ()
          {
              input.focus();

              // Close if already visible
              if (wasOpen)
              {
                  return;
              }

              // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
              input.autocomplete("search", "");
          });
        },

        _source: function (request, response)
        {
            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            response(this.element.children("option").map(function ()
            {
                var text = $(this).text();
                if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                    return {
                        label: text,
                        value: text,
                        option: this
                    };
            }));
        },

        _removeIfInvalid: function (event, ui)
        {

            // Selected an item, nothing to do
            if (ui.item)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
            var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
            this.element.children("option").each(function ()
            {
                if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase)
                {
                    this.selected = valid = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Found a match, nothing to do
            if (valid)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Remove invalid value
            this.input
          .val("")
          .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
          .tooltip("open");
            this.element.val("");
            this._delay(function ()
            {
                this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
            }, 2500);
            this.input.data("ui-autocomplete").term = "";
        },

        _destroy: function ()
        {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Does anyone know how to implement the autopostback functionality with the JQuery combobox code? Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try onchange event? Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203988/jquery-dropdown-selector-autopostback and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342046/jquery-ui-combobox-and-asp-net-web-forms-autopostback

Comment: Thanks for those links!  The second one is what I needed to look at.  I guess the code for the combobox must have changed on their site from time when that post was created until now since there was some differences but nothing too terrible.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late reply. May be it would save your time.

Remove OnSelectedIndexChanged from your drop down list

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdownFacility" />
```

You can call _doPostback event on dropdown list item changes,

```
__doPostBack('<%= upnl.ClientID %>', this.element.attr("id"));
```

look for above line in your code for its implementation

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("custom.combobox", {
        _create: function () {
            this.wrapper = $("<span>")
              .addClass("custom-combobox")
              .insertAfter(this.element);

            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton();
        },

        _createAutocomplete: function () {
            var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
              value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

            this.input = $("<input>")
              .appendTo(this.wrapper)
              .val(value)
              .attr("title", "")
              .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
              .autocomplete({
                  delay: 0,
                  minLength: 0,
                  source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
              })
              .tooltip({
                  tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
              });

            this._on(this.input, {
                autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    this._trigger("select", event, {
                        item: ui.item.option
                    });

                    __doPostBack('<%= upnl.ClientID %>', this.element.attr("id"));
                },

                autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
            });
        },

        _createShowAllButton: function () {
            var input = this.input,
              wasOpen = false;

            $("<a>")
              .attr("tabIndex", -1)
              //.attr("title", "Show All Items")
              //.tooltip()
              .appendTo(this.wrapper)
              .button({
                  icons: {
                      primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                  },
                  text: false
              })
              .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
              .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
              .mousedown(function () {
                  wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
              })
              .click(function () {
                  input.focus();

                  // Close if already visible
                  if (wasOpen) {
                      return;
                  }

                  // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                  input.autocomplete("search", "");
              });
        },

        _source: function (request, response) {
            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            response(this.element.children("option").map(function () {
                var text = $(this).text();
                if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                    return {
                        label: text,
                        value: text,
                        option: this
                    };
            }));
        },

        _removeIfInvalid: function (event, ui) {

            // Selected an item, nothing to do
            if (ui.item) {
                return;
            }

            // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
            var value = this.input.val(),
              valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
              valid = false;
            this.element.children("option").each(function () {
                if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                    this.selected = valid = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Found a match, nothing to do
            if (valid) {
                return;
            }

            // Remove invalid value
            if (value != '') {
                this.input
                  .val("")
                  .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
                  .tooltip("open");
                this.element.val("");
                this._delay(function () {
                    this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
                }, 2500);
                this.input.data("ui-autocomplete").term = "";
            } else {
                this.input.val("");
                this.element.val("");
                this.input.data("ui-autocomplete").term = "";
            }
            __doPostBack('<%= upnl.ClientID %>', this.element.attr("id"));
        },

        _destroy: function () {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```